# How to configure log retention in the latest Keycloak-18.0.0

Tags: logging, rotation, keycloak

I am trying to configure application level log rotation in the latest keycloak-18.0.0, but couldn't find any documentation related to it.

https://www.keycloak.org/server/logging

Could someone guide on this?

Keycloak version:- https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/releases/download/18.0.0/keycloak-18.0.0.zip

I am looking for the configuration similar to size-rotating-file-handler in jboss/Wildfly,

[How to configure PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler in JBoss 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21083960/how-to-configure-periodicsizerotatingfilehandler-in-jboss-7)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Keycloak does not expose this as configuration parameters directly. However, Quarkus does, and you can use Quarkus configuration properties to enable this behaviour.

Under [Migrating Configuration](https://www.keycloak.org/migration/migrating-to-quarkus#_migrating_configuration) in the official documentation, there's a note that you can include a `conf/quarkus.properties` file in your Keycloak file layout.

Then, you can find the Quarkus [Logging Documentation](https://quarkus.io/version/2.7/guides/logging#quarkus-log-logging-log-config_quarkus.log.file-file-logging), which has a few file logging related configuration options. So a quarkus.properties file like this:

```
quarkus.log.file.rotation.max-file-size=5M
quarkus.log.file.rotation.max-backup-index=10
quarkus.log.file.rotation.rotate-on-boot=true
```

Should be able to give you what you need, in combination with the Keycloak file logging options that are already available. Note that you have to be careful to view the Quarkus documentation that is applicable for the Keycloak version you are using. 18 and 19 use Quarkus 2.7. When you upgrade to Keycloak 20, the Quarkus version is 2.13. Newer Quarkus versions often offer better ways to achieve things, so you'll need to keep a lookout when upgrading your Keycloak to the most recent version 20.0.3

Comment: That sounds like the way to go, however after setting up that file with these params, my log file isn't rotating. If anyone manage to do this using quarkus, I would be happy to hear about it